# use CPLEX from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, powershell, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I have a **text** file of *lp* problem

```
   Minimize

   5.8 x_1 + 3 x_2

   subject to

   x_1 + 2.1 x_2 = 6
   3 x_2 < 4.2

   bounds

   x_1 >= 0
   x_2 >= 0

   Integer
   x_1

   end
```

I use these two commands for optimization from Windows PowerShell(or command prompt).

```
   read abc.txt lp
   opt
```

I know cplex can be used from matlab, I added required path and saved it. Matlab R2014a. But don't know proper command(i.e. matlab commands/m-file) to read problem from file and optimize it. also write the solution to a file.

(Text file must be the medium because number of variables will be large.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cplex=Cplex()
>
> cplex.readModel('abc.txt')
>
> cplex.solve

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading model using

```
cplex.readModel('abc.txt');
```

and [`cplexmilp`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/cplexmilp-m.html) for the optimization?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it really helps towards the actual solution `>cplex=Cplex()`
`>cplex.readModel('abc.txt')`
`>cplexlp(cplex.Model)`

first two command I think worked perfectly, as no error appeared, but last command shows **Error using cplexlp (line 254),Not enough input arguments.**

Comment: @Mr.EU I'm glad I could help. You can post your solution as a new answer (and accept it) for future reference. It would be best if the complete answer will be presented as one and not as comments.